# If statement error in erlang program

Tags: erlang

I am new to erlang and have some hard time to get used to it. I wrote simple function and I am getting an error: `Error:(21, -1) erlc: syntax error before: '=='` (Line 21 is the line with: `I == 2 and H == "+" -> calc(T,1,R+H," ");` ). I have no idea what causes the problem, but when I delete line 21 everything works fine. Is this has something to do with "and" statement that I use on line 21? How to use this statement properly?

```
-module(onp).
-author("majew_000").

%% API
-export([]).
-export([onp/1]).
-export([calc/4]).

%I = 0 function just started
%I = 1 function took action sign
%I = 2 action has to be made
%R -> result
%I -> indicator
%A -> sign of an operation (+,-,/,*)
calc([],I,R,A) -> R;
calc([H|T],I,R,A) ->
  if
    I == 0 -> calc(T,1,R+H," ");
    I == 1 -> calc(T,2,R,H);
    I == 2 and H == "+" -> calc(T,1,R+H," ");
    true -> R
 end.

onp([])->[];
onp([H | T])->calc(string:tokens([H|T]," "),0,0," ").
```

Comment: The problem is in the priority of `and`, change line 21 to: `(I == 2) and (H == "+") -> calc(T,1,R+H," ");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can not have `and` in one of `if` guard statements.

You could try to use `andalso` like

```
I == 2 andalso H == "+" -> calc(T,1,R+H," ");
```

which will compile.

There is some convention that dis-advises usage of `if` in favor of `case`, or function clauses.  Since you have this `and`, `case` is somewhat out of the picture (working and ugly example later).  So lets try function clauses:

```
calc([],I,R,A) -> 
   R;

calc([H|T], 0, R, A) ->
   calc(T, 1, R+H, " ");

calc([H|T], 1, R, A) ->
   calc(T, 2, R, H);

calc([ $+ |T], 2, R, A) ->  %% `$+` stands for + character, 
   calc(T, 1, R+H, " ");

calc( _, _, _, _) ->
   R.
```

And you could change "magic numbers" to meaningful atoms, and ensure proper start arguments.

```
calc(List) ->
   calc(List, start, _Rest = 0, _Action = " ").

calc([],I,R,A) -> 
   R;

calc([H|T], start, R, A) ->
   calc(T, took_action, R+H, " ");

calc([H|T], took_action, R, A) ->
   calc(T, make_action, R, H);

calc([ $+|T], make_action, R, A) ->  %% `$+` stands for `+` character, 
   calc(T, took_action, R+H, " ");

calc( _, _, _, _) ->
   R.
```

And then extend you logic even more

```
calc(List) ->
   calc(List, start, _Rest = 0, _Action = " ").

calc([],I,R,A) -> 
   R;

calc([H|T], start, R, A) ->
   calc(T, took_action, R+H, " ");

calc([H|T], took_action, R, A) ->
   calc(T, make_action, R, H);

calc([H|T], make_action, R, A) ->  %% `$+` stands for `+` character, 

   case H of
      $+ ->
         calc(T, took_action, R+H, " ");
      $- ->
         calc(T, took_action, R-H, " ");
  [ .... ]
   end

calc( _, _, _, _) ->
   R.
```

But here you can see that you are starting to add `H` which is character (still based on your `if` code).  So I guess, you should be doing `case` on `A` like action, and keep on adding/multiplying/... `H` with `R`.